# What's the fastest way to compare point elements with each other？I have used Nested for loop to do that, but it's very slow

Tags: c++, opencv, for-loop, dictionary, vector

I want to find the points which the distant between points less than 3.For example, some points as follow,
(220,221)(220,119)(220,220)(20,90)(220,222).
I use (220,221) to find points.Then i can get (220,221)(220,119)(220,220)(220,222)
I use (220,119) to find points.Then i can get (220,221)(220,119)(220,220)
I have used Nested for loop to do that, but it's very slow.It worked inefficiently.The code as follow,

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<Point>  p;
    vector<Point> temp;
    vector<vector<Point> > centerbox;

    p.push_back(Point(110, 110));
    p.push_back(Point(110, 111));
    p.push_back(Point(110, 110));
    p.push_back(Point(110, 112));
    p.push_back(Point(111, 112));
    p.push_back(Point(150, 111));


    for (vector<Point> ::iterator iter1 = p.begin(); iter1 != p.end(); ++iter1) {


        for (vector<Point> ::iterator iter2 = p.begin(); iter2 != p.end();) {



            if (abs((*iter1).x - (*iter2).x) + abs((*iter1).y - (*iter2).y) < 3) {

                temp.push_back((*iter2));
                ++iter2;
            }
            else {
                ++iter2;
            }
        }


        centerbox.push_back(temp);

        temp.clear();

    }

        return 0;
}
```

How can i do to make faster than using Nested for loop?

Comment: you could use space partitioning/hashing techniques to "sort" your points into bins. After that for a fixed maximum distance you only have to compare each point with the points in few neighboring bins.

Comment: the easiest way to make it faster would be to use the symmetry.. if p1 has dist of < 3 to p2 you can do both: add p2 to result of p1 and add p1 to result of p2. then for the next point you can can ignore all previous points because you computed their distances already. example: 5 points you dont need 25 (quadratic) point comparisons but 5+4+3+2+1=15 or (if you dont compare each point to itself) 4+3+2+1=10

Comment: Use simple indexing instead of iterators and also if you know about the upper limit on number of points then use an array instead of vector.

Comment: Using `std::vector::reserve` and `std::vector::emplace` should give you some performance increase.

Comment: thanks for everyone！I wanted to use sort before.but  sort  cost much time,doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 20000 random points with about 27 neighbors for each point this function gave me a speed-up. It needed about 33% less time than your original method.

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > findNeighborsOptimized(std::vector<cv::Point> p, float maxDistance = 3.0f)
{

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > centerbox(p.size()); // already create a output vector for each input point

    /*
    // if you  have enough memory, you can reserve enough space for each point. If not, just remove this part, which will result in a lot of reallocations later.
    //unsigned int reserveSize = p.size(); // definitely enough space so no reallocations will happen but probably too much space reserved...
    //unsigned int reserveSize = p.size()/2; 
    //unsigned int reserveSize = p.size()/3;
    //unsigned int reserveSize = p.size()/10;
    unsigned int reserveSize = 1;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<centerbox.size(); ++i)
    {
        centerbox[i].reserve(reserveSize);
    }
    */
    // for me it turned out to be slower to reserve a lot of memory... maybe because of caching?!?
    // will depend on the average number of neighbors for each point...


    for(unsigned int j=0; j<p.size(); ++j)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point> & p1Neighbors = centerbox[j];

        // create a reference to the point so that we dont need to GET it several times
         cv::Point & p1 = p[j];
         //p1Neighbors.push_back(p1); // uncomment this if you want to show the point be a neighbor of itself (dist to itself is alway == 0).
         // for p2 ignore p1 and start at the next point

         for(unsigned int i=j+1; i<p.size(); ++i)
         {
             cv::Point & p2 = p[i];

             // instead you might want to use cv::norm(p1-p2) or something, but I'll stay at your original logic
            if(abs(diff.x) + abs(diff.y) < maxDistance)
             {
                 p1Neighbors.push_back(p2);
                 // add p1 to neighbors of p2 too
                 centerbox[j].push_back(p1);
             }
         }
    }


    return centerbox;
}
```

depending on the number of points you have in your applications and depending on their distribution, space partitioning or spatial hashing might give you mugh better improvement.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.you said "spatial hashing might give you mugh better improvement".I had used unordered_mulitmap to do that,but i don't know how to compare the points.Different point has different hashcode,so i can't put the points into one bucket to compare points.So i wrote a hash function that make all points have same hashcode that will be put into same bucket.Then compare to each other by using hash compare function.But I thank all points have one hashcode is not a good idea.Do you have some idea?Can you show the code that using hashing to find points in my case.Thanks in advance!

Comment: never used spatial hashing, only seen it in a lecture. but try http://zufallsgenerator.github.io/2014/01/26/visually-comparing-algorithms/ and http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/spatial-hashing-r2697

Answer (score -1):

`push_back` creates a copy of the object you send it, so storing a pointer to Point instead of the whole Point object may be faster.

You could also use `std::vector<T>::reserve` to reserve space in the temp vector in advance. This will reduce the chance that `push_back` reallocates memory (which is slow!).